# jquery bind event depends on situation

Tags: jquery

I want to know about jquery. Can we bind event depending on the variables / situation / another event?

for example, If the var X is 0, a div could be clicked, meanwhile if the var X is 1, the same div could not be clicked.

I made this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hKkVD/4/
.of course it's not working, but you get the idea.

EDIT : Sorry I made some confusion. I need the variable to be checked BEFORE the click event is triggered.

So basically the variable is to check (and toggle) whether the event is permitted or not. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your JavaScript wasn't far off, but for me (in Chrome anyway), the alert keyword seems to have caused problems. Check out my updated code here http://jsfiddle.net/cchana/6UeeG/

```
var alertMe = 0;

$("#toggle").click(function(){
   if (alertMe == 0){
       $("#toggle").text('turn alert off');
       alertMe = 1;
   }   
   else {
       $("#toggle").text('turn alert on');
       alertMe = 0;                
   }       
});

$("#clickme").click(function() {
    if(alertMe == 1) {
        alert("hey i could be clicked");
    }
});
```

It makes sense to do the check inside the function, rather than define two separate function calls as only the first condition that is met will be bound to the element.

Comment: thanks, but no. In my problem, I don't want the click to be triggered before variable check. Is that possible?

Comment: The click will only be triggered if the condition is met. Amended my answer to show this, now the click event will always fire, but the code is only executed when the conditions are met. This is far more efficient than binding the click event, removing it and re-binding it each time.

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure if you looking for something like this but you can check this url.I updated your demo.

http://jsfiddle.net/hKkVD/1/

Comment: Works but in the wrong sense (alerts when OFF, but not when ON).

Comment: he said "the same div could not be clicked." it means not alert when the value is not vaild. i think showing alert is wrong.

Comment: i dont think it is possible. If i understand you truely, because div don't have clickable attribute. If u wanna do control onclick action you should trigger it.

Answer (score 0):

If you used any other name for your flag your code would have worked. The thing is that ny defining a flag 'alert', you are overwriting the initial alert function. So all you have to do is change the name of your flag or  specifically call the global function like this : 'window.alert()'. Here's a fiddle with the flag name changed : http://jsfiddle.net/hKkVD/2/

Comment: even with correct variable names, only the first 'loaded' event is working. The other one doesn't. no matter what the variable is.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use `alert` as a variable name. That will deny access to the native `alert()` method.

Also, As written your code tests the value of `alert` before putting the click handler in place. I expect that what you want is to test the value of `alert` inside a click handler.

```
var b_alert = false;//boolean_alert
$("#toggle").click(function() {
    b_alert = !b_alert;
    $(this).text(b_alert ? 'turn alert off' : 'turn alert on');
});

$("#clickme").click(function() {
    if (b_alert) {
        alert('Hey I could be clicked!');
    }
    else {
        //do nothing
    }
});
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qdUp7/)

Comment: yeah, I wrote that fiddle without test it before, thinking it would serve just as some kind of guideline. But the alert is not my real problem, please see my updated post. thanks!

Comment: Now I'm confused. Checking the variable "BEFORE the click event is triggered" doesn't make any sense. Your fiddle checks before the click handler is attached, which is fine if that's what you want. The only other alternative is to check the variable when each click event occurs; that what my answer and others have suggested.

Comment: yeah, I want to check whether the click event is allowed or not before the event is triggered. I did that, but only the first event found was applied (see the gion_13 post). Perhaps my logic is not right or is it not possible, eh?

Comment: If you test the var before a click handler is attached, ie as a one-off check on page load, then you will only attach one of the two possible behaviours - the other behaviour is discarded. If however you perform the test within the loop as suggested by myself and others, then both behaviours are available within the click handler and will be selected in reposnse to the test each time a click occurs. This is a very common approach to coding behaviour that must respond to varying state.